# Windows 10 route change a single route

Tags: windows, route

among other routes I have one that looks like this:

```
Network Destination   Netmask           Gateway        Interface        Metric
192.168.244.7         255.255.255.255   192.168.244.80   192.168.244.24   125
```

I would like to only change the Gateway to be:

```
Network Destination   Netmask           Gateway          Interface        Metric
192.168.244.7         255.255.255.255   192.168.244.85   192.168.244.24   125
```

I have tried to use the route change method like this:

```
route change 192.168.244.7 mask 255.255.255.255 gateway 192.168.244.85 192.168.244.24 metric 125
```

But when I run it, I receive "bad argument 192.168.244.85"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for the command `route change` only needs the new gateway, not the old one; also, the "gateway" keyword is only a placeholder in the command help, it should not be actually typed.

Try this:

```
route change 192.168.244.7 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.244.85
```